# Mysql order result with subgroups order

Tags: sql, mariadb

As example I have table

| id | param1 | param2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | c | 1 |
| 2 | a | 2 |
| 3 | d | 3 |
| 4 | a | 1 |
| 5 | b | 3 |
| 6 | a | 3 |
| 7 | e | 4 |

pair param1&param2 is unique

I want to get this result where any items with same param1 grouped by id in own subgroup

| id | param1 | param2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | c | 1 |
| 2 | a | 2 |
| 4 | a | 1 |
| 6 | a | 3 |
| 3 | d | 3 |
| 5 | b | 3 |
| 7 | e | 4 |

Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: Please add more explanation for the exact order you require... For example, but not limited to: why does the "group" with `param1=c` precede the "group" with `param1=a`? Why does the row with `param1=a`, `param2=2`precede the row with `param1=a`, `param2=1`?

Comment: what do you mean by subgroup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the assumption that "groups" are ordered according to the `MIN(ID)` in the "group", and that rows within a "group" are ordered according to the `id`...

```
WITH
  summarised AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    MIN(id) OVER (PARTITION BY param1) AS group_min_id
  FROM
    YourTable
) 
SELECT
  *
FROM
  summarised
ORDER BY
  group_min_id,
  id
```

Using correlated sub-query in place of window function...

```
SELECT
  *,
  (SELECT MIN(id) FROM yourTable AS lookup WHERE lookup.param1 = yourTable.param1) AS group_min_id
FROM
  yourTable
ORDER BY
  group_min_id,
  id
```

Comment: that's very useful, thanks
but for example for older versions of mysql or any other db (where window functions is not implemented) is any ways to do this?